# BiblaTeX: Not printing bibliography, includes bib label in final PDF

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliography (.bib) file:

```
@article{tong2012string,
author = {D. Tong},
title = {{L}ectures on {S}tring {T}heory},
year = {2012},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
eprint = {0908.0333},
primaryClass = {hep-th}}
```

In my LaTeX file, I included:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

In addition, I used, `\cite{tong2012string}` next to where I'd like the [1] to appear, and finally attempted to print the bibliography using `\printbibliography`.

---

**What Happened:**

Instead of including [1], in the PDF it printed [tong2012string] in bold. Also, the blbiography was not printed at all. I've tried:

- Making sure I'm using biber by specifying 'backend=biber'
- Deleting any auxiliary files that may have been causing the problem

However, my .blg file is always the same:

```
    This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: String.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file String.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file String.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file String.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

---

**Windows 7**, using **TeXStudio** and **MiKTeX**

---

**Working Example**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\cite{tong2012string}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

See above for .bib file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Sverre: I'm on it, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: You're running `bibtex`, not `biber`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: How do I fix that? I specified "backend=bibtex", is that not enough?

Comment: You have specified `backend=biber`, which means you have to compile with the sequence `pdflatex` - `biber` - `pdflatex`. If you switch to `backend=bibtex` then you can run `pdflatex` - `bibtex` - `pdflatex`, or F6 - F11 - F6 in TeXstudio.

Comment: There is some info on running `biber` from TeXstudio in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154754#154754

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thank you for the link, it solved the problem!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Do you know how I can fix the style? I've got it on numeric, but it prints out:  D. Tong. "Lectures on String Theory". In: (2012). arXiv: [arXiv:0908.0333 [hep-th]]  How can I get the title to be italicized, and the 'in' removed?

Comment: @user1997744 In general you should open a new question for new questions rather than asking in comments, but those questions are answered elsewhere on this Exchange - I can't find them right now, but a little Google might help! Welcome! :-)

Comment: @darthbith: In case you were curious, my mistake was setting the style using bibstyle, rather than the style command :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you actually run the `biber` command between runs of latex:

```
   latex test.tex
   biber test
   latex test.tex
```